# Is there any way to upgrade from KDE 4 to 5 on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, kde, upgrade, kde4

Earlier you could install KDE5 via repository using Project Neon, like these: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/07/how-to-install-plasma-5-in-kubuntu-1410.html, but unfortunately PPA maintainer deleted it, so this method isn't working anymore.

Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Kde 5 Plasma with Mint 17 isn’t stable . you should wait for the stable version to come . Meanwhile if you want the taste then you can try latest kubuntu 15.04 with KDE 5 [With Kubuntu it is Still in Beta 2](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/VividVervet/Beta2/Kubuntu)